# Type-safe array of generic objects without any in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a following use case: I have a highly configurable UI component, involving generic types. I store this configuration in an array, allowing me to generate an arbitrary number of these in the UI by mapping over it. Let's say the configuration looks like this (simplified case, it's also [available in this Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2AcwDwAqAfMgN4BQyVyAJhPAK4A2YAXMgQNyXVwBucYEzgAjJhFQALdMCQBndgEEoUOAE9CRbgF9y5APQAqcgUkoAjgwhywwTMmALkAd0lwwyMGoAOKOdOYaFxQGORQwdGQILHQoJHIIREko8QBbaI90GGQ4EByVdWQs5ARMbBw5B0rQOl8QOnAc+pLMOUdIcAB+ckN9PQN9ZAAhRQARclKQGxasXCdlVQ0MWfxctSISAF5kAG0eKlJaejhmNmQAFgAmABocgSFRcSkZeXYdgEZb94BmW6uAXWQ2mu+zIR0YLHYACI4FDbvxBMIxBJpLJrG93oDtFR9INvHA5GFKl5fCUzAgANbIAAUIjgNFuEDSGSqRWyJJQy3KeBsUFAOCIAEpyP89LjkIpkAAZACSBAIUoAosNFfLFQAlCatDyTcpyS5KApLMq4HlgPkgHDIAA+yBADFSImgG2Q2z21DBdAhZyu8PuSKeqNeu0+yB+f0uWJBHsOXpOkOQMLhd0RjxRL3RIajOLxBKJnh8KAQ5KptPpwpj4PjZyTftTyOeaKcH1uSezyHFED40U8kkcyHxhOsBdJxYglJpzliYXhTCY6GclVSwAAHvzkAxvCPh6BkG1LeIUhB0uAK9RY8dTtDYXWHg2g5mduarFic73+-AhJVqTh0OgGcELi5JkIBMGoe7muuuRBPajrQHIwqigMyAAOIAPJoaM3RAA)):

```
interface Config<T> {
  default: T;
  availableChoices: Array<T>
}
```

then my array looks like this:

```
const configs: Array<Config<???>> = [
    { default: 42, availableChoices: [1, 13, 42] },
    { default: "a", availableChoices: ["a", "b"] }
]
```

The question is: what should the type `???` be to enforce consistency of a type in all single elements? I tries with `any`, but it doesn't work the way it should (not a big surprise to be honest):

```
// BAD
const configs: Array<Config<any>> = [
    { default: 42, availableChoices: [1, 13, 42] },
    { default: "a", availableChoices: [1] }  // passes type check (bad, element is of type Config<string>)
]
```

Union type works pretty much the same (except it disallows other types, at least that):

```
// A LITTLE BETTER
const configs2: Array<Config<string | number>> = [
    { default: 42, availableChoices: [1, 13, 42] },
    { default: "a", availableChoices: [1] },  // passes type check (bad)
    { default: "a", availableChoices: [1, "a"] },  // even this passes type check (worse, allows mixing up types in single element)
    { default: "a", availableChoices: [true] }  // this fails (good, we want only string and numbers)
]
```

Is that possible to enforce "same type parameter" on every single element of the array? As far as I know, e.g. Scala allows it with `_`:

```
const configs: Array<Config<_>> = [...]  // API I'd love having
```

What are solutions in other languages and possible workarounds?

**NOTE: it's strictly necessary to use generic in this use case, as the real config is a bit more sophisticated and involves selectors and action creators)**

Comment: You can enforce this is you use an extra function and some conditional types. Out of the box it will not be possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest you can do is use union type at the level of `Config` type

```
const configs: Array<Config<number> | Config<string>> = [
    { default: 42, availableChoices: [1, 13, 42] },
    { default: "a", availableChoices: ["a", "b"] }
]
```

Type `Config<number> | Config<string>` says that array can have both types, but `Config` rules are fully fulfilled in every of them.

It means that when your `default` will be a number, then the same needs to be in `availableChoices`.

Your trying with `Config<number | string>` were wrong because such union allows on string and numbers in `default` and `availableChoices` properties. The difference is that the union on level of `Config` maintain the whole object with one type.

On type level its not possible to define some utility which will ensure that `Config` not considers any union type.

What I would suggest is to create value constructor in order to remove need to create many type declaration. Consider:

```
const makeConfig = <T>(a: Config<T>): typeof a => a

const configs = [
    makeConfig({ default: 1, availableChoices: [1, 13, 42] }),
    makeConfig({ default: "a", availableChoices: ["a", "b"] }),
]
```

Its little more to write but `configs` is properly inferred as `(Config<number> | Config<string>)[]` with 0 type declaration.

Comment: Hmm, this is nice, but in my case this would get reeeeaaaly long for many types (and to be honest, I don't really care for internal type, as long as it is consistent), isn't there any better way?

Comment: U can use function as config constructor. Let me add this, give me a second

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you mean and I believe this should fix the problem :D

Comment: The thing is to try to infer the types by the given structure, and functions can do that :D

Comment: Write you some data constructor, its not ideal solution but that what I got after some time of trying to solve it at type level